Topic modelling outputs are gender biased?
Has anyone had this issue?
My topic modelling seems to be presenting responses that are very dominated by male respondents.
The volume of responses across three different questions is over 800 in each case, and the data set does not have anything that labels the responses in any way.
Effectively, they are just open text sentences and one variable being processed each time.
But, when I trace back the quote to the original respondent, in 75% of the cases, across all three different questions, the respondents were male.
Anyone have a clue what's going on? or how I could interogate the data for anything else that might link each response? I've manually looked at punctuation, capitalisation, reference to themselves ("i do this...", and sentence length, and nothing is obvious.
Help, please?
I've manually looked at punctuation, capitalisation, reference to themselves ("i do this...", and sentence length, and nothing is obvious.
#UPDATE:
My outputs also only seem to include responses of 15 words or longer. The gender split within this subgroup (50:50) is still not inline with the skewed gender output in the models (75:25 towards male)

Could you explain how is this question related to python? Thanks

Are maybe the inputs gender-biased already? Like 600 responses from males and 200 not from males?

My code is in python.
Looked at the gender split and it's almost exactly 50:50

BTW - This doesn't look like a programming question; even if it involves a program, it's more about than data science than the development of software.

Try shuffling your training set.

thanks @JonSG
what do you mean by shuffling?

thanks @Anerdw. Yeah I get what you're saying. I guess I'm hoping the coders in here are familiar with LDA enough to know a bit about the possible limitations or biases.
are there other forums that would be more appropriate to ask in? cheers

If your training data packs training data together by any factor, it can introduce bias. Prior to training (perhaps when you split into (train/test) I would random.shuffle() the training data to see if that helped mitigate some of the bender bias.

This Meta post has some guidance, but make sure to read the help center before posting a question anywhere.

thanks @JonSG. this is unsupervised data and I'm not training it, but that's a very interesting suggestion and I'll look to bring in that method. much appreciated.
